# Xamarin ContentPage BackgroundImage property crashes app on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, background, crash, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms to produce a TabbedPage consisting of more ContentPages. This is the part of code causing trouble:

```
    public void launchMainDesign(object s, EventArgs e) {
        MainPage = new TabbedPage {
            Children = {
                new ContentPage {
                    Title = "Login",
                    Content = pages.loginContent,
                    BackgroundImage = "bgmain.jpg"
                },
                new ContentPage {
                    Title = "Sign Up",
                    Content = pages.signUpContent,
                    BackgroundImage = "bgmain.jpg"
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

It seems absolutely fine. I have both the images in my Drawable directory, with the build action set to "AndroidResource".

Whenever the launchMainDesign() function is fired by pressing a button, the app crashes immediately, both in emulator and a build version of the app on a tablet. Unfortunately, I can't test on iOS and WP.

I even tried putting the whole inside part of the function in a try/catch block and print out the exception, but the app just crashes nevertheless.

I am desperately trying to solve this simple problem for about a week now. No one seems to be having exactly the same issue as me. Weirdest thing is, I have a different app where I use exactly the same method and it works just fine. Can the Android Theme be causing this (I'm using Holo, in the working app, there's no theme specified)? That seems to be the only difference.

I also don't think this is caused by RAM struggles, as the image is only about 700 kilobytes (1080x1920) - for this example, I've only used one image.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a memory issue, because even do the size is not big depending on the device resolution it might be trying to scale the image to the device dimensions.

Try checking this README:

https://github.com/xamarin/customer-success/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/SliderView/README.md

Explains Xamarin.Forms Android Image Memory Management so could help you get around the issue you might be having.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, but I'm sure it's not the memory; I tried using the exactly same images that the working app uses and it still causes the same problems.

Comment: I have the same issue. It works *fine* in the emulator. However, on a real device, it goes boom. Looking at LogCat, it shows Canvas: Trying to draw too large. I'll try a smaller image.

Comment: Changing my width to 1080, instead of greater than 1080, appears to have solved the issue on my Galaxy S7. The emulator had no issues, but apparently the device did. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Found the TabbedPage got a lot faster on Android when I used JPEG backgrounds no more than 720px wide. Much better :) Hope that helps!